# Azure Search alphanumeric order

Tags: azure, lucene

Is there a way to order results in Azure Search by another order than the default one ?

In my case, I have entries which number looks something like that : L1-1, L1-2, L2-1, L10-1, D1-1, etc...

I would like to do two things :

- Most of all, order in alphanumeric order, not alphabetical, by which I mean that I want the order :

> L1-1, L1-2, L2-1, L10-1

and not

> L1-1, L1-2, L10-1, L2-1

Azure search default order gives me the second one.

- If possible, I would also like to add some salt by specifying a custom order for first char (let's say L > D > Q).

For now, I retrieve all results, then order by that custom order, but that prevents me from building a paging or "infinite loading" system (I can't retrieve my results 10 by 10 if they are in the wrong order).

Cheers !